# Visual Studio Tab Labeled Wrongly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me.  I am trying to follow along in self guided course that didn't state the extension installs until it was too late.

What I mean by that is they just told me to install Visual Studio Code, and than went ahead with the lesson.  After installing a prompt asked me while I was typing this if I wanted to install C#.  I approved, and then cpl minutes later the instructor said I only needed to install live server.  I also noticed their tab was labeled JS, but my tab was labeled C#.

I uninstalled C#, but still didn't get rid of it.  I installed a Java Script extension still didn't get rid of it.  I closed and opened multiple times.  I uninstalled/reinstalled multiple times.  Even restarted my computer a a couple of times.  Everyone else has the JS, but I have the C#.

Working on a windows  10 I think i5 processor.

What do you think I should do?

[image: Why is my java script tab labed C#]

Comment: First, "Visual Studio" and "Visual Studio Code" are very different applications. Please correct this in your title and tags. Second, what's the extension of your file? ".cs"? Third, "Java" and "JavaScript" are _VERY_ different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it..... all I had to do was go to "save as" and choose java script and now its yellow like everyone else's.

Comment: When you post about JavaScript be careful to not include spaces in the name to avoid confusion.